# Sql trigger not working correctly, deleting to logtable

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, triggers

this trigger is designed to log password changes to a logtable, when you change the password, the old password goes to the table, and it will do that for 5 passwords, when it exceeds the number of 5, it will remove the oldest password to make room for newer ones

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CheckCount]
       ON  [dbo].[LogPassword]
       AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @nummer int
        set @nummer = (Select count(*) from logpassword WHERE beheerderID = (SELECT u.beheerderid FROM INSERTED u)) 
        IF (@nummer > 5)
        BEGIN   
        DELETE FROM logpassword WHERE changedate = (SELECT MIN(changedate) from logpassword) AND beheerderID = (SELECT u.beheerderid FROM INSERTED u
    END
```

This is supposed to remove the oldest row from the LogTable, now this works perfectly when you only have 1 ID, if there are 5 rows in the table, and you change the password, the newest one gets inserted, and the oldest will be removed. However, if you have 2 persons(2 ID's) one will still work, but the other will go beyond 5 to infinity, I'm thinking the problem lies with

`AND beheerderID = (SELECT u.beheerderid FROM INSERTED u`

I have tried to make it work but i dont understand what the problem is, which makes it kind of hard to solve the problem :/

Comment: passwords in plaintext? No. No. NO.

Comment: = sub-select is a bit scary, do IN sub-select, just in case.

Comment: everyone keeps saying nono to that and i know its bad, but its hashed haha :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a problem whith that line:

```
DELETE FROM logpassword WHERE changedate = (SELECT MIN(changedate) from logpassword) AND beheerderID = (SELECT u.beheerderid FROM INSERTED u)
```

When you check for the min(changedate) you get the min of all users, instead of looking only the rows whith the same beheerderid.

change your subselect:

```
(SELECT MIN(changedate) from logpassword)
```

by this one:

```
(SELECT MIN(changedate) from logpassword where beheerderID=(SELECT u.beheerderid FROM INSERTED u) )
```

Comment: wow.. i feel kind of dumb now, was that dumb of me? :P thanks a lot mate!

Comment: jejeje, we usually need more than 2 eyes. ;)